# PHP cross domain requests

Tags: php, cross-domain

I am a green programmer and I was originally trying to make cross domain requests in JS. I quickly learned that this is not allowed. Unlike similar questions posted on here, I would like to see if I can use PHP to make them for me instead of JSONP requests. Is this possible?

Simple workflow...

```
BROWSER: POST to my PHP the request-payload & request-headers

PHP: POST to Other Domain's URL the request-payload & request-headers

Other Domain: Process Request and send response

PHP: Send the Response-Content and Response-Header Info back to the browser
```

Here is what I am trying to work with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb969500%28v=office.12%29.aspx

My goal is to make a Communicator Web Access Client that is web based and mobile friendly.

A link to a working example would be awesome!

Comment: What you are looking for is CURL ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).

Comment: even better is ROLLING CURL (MULTi CURL)

Comment: I have looked at CURL but I dont see(most likely my bad) how this is executed. Could you show me a generic example of posting and getting the response using CURL?

Comment: There is one titled 'Basic curl example' on the same site... http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

CURL yould be your option in this case, something simple as:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://otherdomain.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

In this case, $result would contain the html code of the site. Please be aware that it doesn't going to execute any javascript as if you were visiting the site on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about web services and seems that the goal is process payments. Any major payment gateway have APIs prepared for that. In any case you can study by your own. Here a good starting point http://ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest